# Why am I getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'?

Tags: python, arduino

I have created a bareduino to measure the temperature in the garden. 
When I am reading the serial data from the receiver directly from the terminal I get this:

> ~ $ screen /dev/ttyUSB1 9600

```
   Requesting temperature...DONE
   Device 1 (index 0) = 19.62 Degrees C
   VCC = 5.89 Volts
   VCC = 96.99 %

   Requesting temperature...DONE
   Device 1 (index 0) = 19.62 Degrees C
   VCC = 5.89 Volts
   VCC = 96.99 %
```

And so one.

I have the following script working, but sometimes after a period of running I am getting an error I do not understand.

> /var/python $ cat rx4.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# rx4.py serial_port port_speed
#
import serial, sys
import re
import time
import datetime
import pymysql

if (len(sys.argv) != 3):
   print "command line: rx.py serial_port port_speed"
   sys.exit()
port = sys.argv[1]
speed = int(sys.argv[2])
ser = serial.Serial(port,speed)
ser.setDTR()
ser.flushInput()
print 'Welcome to remote bareduino temprature! Waiting for data...'
data = []
while 1:
  count = 0
  data = []
  while (count < 5):
    count += 1
    x = ser.readline()
    data.append(x)
  if data:
    temperatur = re.search(' = (.*?) Degrees C', data[2]).group(1)
    volts = re.search('VCC = (.*?) ', data[3]).group(1)
    batt =  re.search('VCC = (.*?) \%', data[4]).group(1)
  print 'print data'
  print data

  conn = pymysql.connect(host='10.0.0.175', port=3306, user='python', passwd='testcode', db='test2')
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO 28b65eb2(celsius,voltproc,volt) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (temperatur, batt, volts))
  conn.commit()
  cur.close
  conn.close()

  print temperatur, u'\u00b0'
  print volts, u'\u26A1'
  print u"\U0001F50B", batt, u"\u0025"
```

> /var/python $ python rx4.py /dev/ttyUSB1 9600

```
Welcome to remote bareduino temprature! Waiting for data...
print data
['\r\n', 'Requesting temperature...DONE\r\n', 'Device 1 (index 0) = 20.69 Degrees C\r\n', 'VCC = 5.89 Volts\r\n', 'VCC = 96.14 %\r\n']
20.69 °
5.89 ⚡
 96.14 %
print data
['\r\n', 'Requesting temperature...DONE\r\n', 'Device 1 (index 0) = 20.69 Degrees C\r\n', 'VCC = 5.89 Volts\r\n', 'VCC = 96.14 %\r\n']
20.69 °
5.89 ⚡
 96.14 %
```

I getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'?
```

On the line with `temperatur = re.search(' = (.*?) Degrees C', data[2]).group(1)`

Comment: For debugging it would be useful to print `data` *before* the line that gives the error. That way you can see if it looks strange so that it doesn't match the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

If `re.search` can't match your regex in a string, it will return `None` ([documents](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)). The `None` object has no attributes at all, so trying to access the `group` attribute raises the error.

To fix the error, you need to either change your regex so that `re.search` matches something, explicitly check that `re.search` has not returned `None` and if so skip the lines where you access the matches groups, or catch the error with `try`/`except` block.

For example, you could write:

```
match = re.search(' = (.*?) Degrees C', data[2])
if match is not None:
     temperatur = match.group(1)
else:
     temperatur = "unknown" # or any other value
```

Comment: @KristianMogensKogut - glad it helped! If you like, you can mark the answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) - there should be a tick symbol above.